# Jackrabbit oak1.4.6 with mongo DB 3.2 datastore high rapid growth in disk usage with the 200GB daily and re-indexing continually

Tags: mongodb, lucene, jackrabbit-oak

With above mentioned jackrabbit and mongoDB versions with about 4TB of data we see lucene Re-indexing is happening continually and on daily basis 200GB of the disk space is consumed.
Any help is really appreciated as this is happening in one of the production box.

Answer (score 0):

This version is four years old, and has had *20* minor releases since (see http://jackrabbit.apache.org/jcr/downloads.html#oak1.4). I would recommend updating, and, if the problem persists, send email to the jackrabbit users mailing list.